# Ethers fails to parse raw transaction

Tags: ethers.js, raw-transaction

I'm trying to parse the raw transaction of this transaction on mainnet: `0x2cd10c5a49963ea7009be96fd4651e4009c719f680096cd8c66c083b48ba5de6`.

The hex encoding of the raw signed transaction is

```
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
```

When decoding with `ethers`, this results in the following error:

```
const ethers = require('ethers')

function main() {
    const raw = '0xb9019602f9019201428459682f00850dba9fbbf48303793c947a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d80b9012438ed1739000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012a16030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004ddd75eac00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0000000000000000000000000018c393f77835b9f37ad8500bcbf739bff9f82ce0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061b7209200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030000000000000000000000002b89bf8ba858cd2fcee1fada378d5cd6936968be000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48c001a0c57a8fc131811dce50bbd061ff1f24a6f32a067ce629a51ca3c08287479aac9ea01521d308b35ce9710a19a52f8eaeff43f9b75d2b0f45f515de6a3b5d0c6d6f06'
    const tx = ethers.utils.parseTransaction(raw)
    console.log(tx)
}

main()
```

**Output**: `Error: invalid raw transaction`.

What needs to be fixed to parse this transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an object to `.parseTransaction`:

```
const raw = '0xb9019602f9019201428459682f00850dba9fbbf48303793c947a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d80b9012438ed173900000...'
const tx = ethers.utils.parseTransaction({ data: raw })
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseTransaction` works on a serialized ethers transaction.

I think what you're looking for might be `getTransaction` which receives the tx hash and returns the tx info. [Documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getTransaction)

Answer (score 0):

You need the ABI of that contract, then you'll be able to decode it.

Using `abi-decoder` library, place the whole ABI in `abi.js` as `module.exports=[...ABI...]` -

```
    const abiDecoder = require('abi-decoder');
    abiDecoder.addABI(require('./abi'));
    const data = '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';
    const decodedData = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(decodedData));
```

result -

```
{"name":"swapExactTokensForTokens","params":[{"name":"amountIn","value":"5001052928","type":"uint256"},{"name":"amountOutMin","value":"20901748396","type":"uint256"},{"name":"path","value":["0x2b89bf8ba858cd2fcee1fada378d5cd6936968be","0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2","0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48"],"type":"address[]"},{"name":"to","value":"0x018c393f77835b9f37ad8500bcbf739bff9f82ce","type":"address"},{"name":"deadline","value":"1639391378","type":"uint256"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided raw tx hex is not valid. You can check here: https://rawtxdecode.in/

The valid raw tx hex for this tx is:

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

Here is the decoded response for valid tx hex

```
{
  "chainId": "1",
  "type": "EIP-1559",
  "valid": true,
  "hash": "0x2cd10c5a49963ea7009be96fd4651e4009c719f680096cd8c66c083b48ba5de6",
  "nonce": "66",
  "gasLimit": "227644",
  "maxFeePerGas": "58965605364",
  "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "1500000000",
  "from": "0x018C393F77835b9f37aD8500bCBF739Bff9F82CE",
  "to": "0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d",
  "publicKey": "0x0409182ae303dc6bf92ffaa49834c59aa19f2bfb4af63be839771cbd6b398cff8c085af0050ad8205778d33204e7640da16afcfb28bbff9bae0f741bcedc713fd5",
  "v": "01",
  "r": "c57a8fc131811dce50bbd061ff1f24a6f32a067ce629a51ca3c08287479aac9e",
  "s": "1521d308b35ce9710a19a52f8eaeff43f9b75d2b0f45f515de6a3b5d0c6d6f06",
  "value": "0",
  "data": "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",
  "functionHash": "0x38ed1739",
  "possibleFunctions": [
    {
      "definition": "swapExactTokensForTokens(uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)",
      "decodedInputs": [
        "5001052928",
        "20901748396",
        [
          "0x2B89bF8ba858cd2FCee1faDa378D5cd6936968Be",
          "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
          "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48"
        ],
        "0x018C393F77835b9f37aD8500bCBF739Bff9F82CE",
        "1639391378"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by indicating how/where you found the correct hex string.